# Assert signature of the function that is called to return & (reference)

Tags: c++, debugging, pass-by-reference, c++14, assert

Is it possible to assert type of a function that I call to return by reference?

The assertion is expected to happen only at compile time (but not required).

It is useful for debugging purpose.

### Example

I have a simple `std::vector<T>` encapsulator as followed:-

```
template<class T> class CustomArray{
    //..... some datastructure ...
    T& get(int index) { ... }
}
```

Some game/business logic may use this class e.g.

```
CustomArray<CreditCard> array ;
//... do some business logic
CreditCard& c= array.get(0);
c.pinNumber = 1403; //modification
```

The modification of **pinNumber** effects the value in CustomArray, nice.

If someone in my team want to use his own data structure and edit my code e.g.

```
HisCustomArray<CreditCard> array ;
//replace the line : CustomArray<CreditCard> array
```

I want an automatic **weak** way to ensure that HisCustomArray::get(int) always return as T& not T, otherwise the line will be broken.

```
 c.pinNumber = 1403;
```

I expect something similar to:

```
CustomArray<CreditCard> array ;
assertReturn_JUST_DUMMY(   array::get(int)  , CreditCard& ); //possible format
//.... other business logic ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `static_assert` and `std::is_reference` to get what you are looking for.

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> class CustomArray{
   public:
    T& get(int index) {return data;}
    T data;
};

template<class T> class HisCustomArray{
   public:
    T get(int index) {return data;}
    T data;
};

struct CreditCard {};

int main()
{
   CustomArray<CreditCard> array1;
   static_assert(std::is_reference<decltype(array1.get(0))>::value,
                 "Need a reference returning function.");
   CreditCard& c1 = array1.get(0);

   HisCustomArray<CreditCard> array2;
   static_assert(std::is_reference<decltype(array2.get(0))>::value,
                 "Need a reference returning function.");
}
```

The compiler does an assert at compiler time for `array2`.

Error message from g++ 4.8.4:

```
socc.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
socc.cc:24:4: error: static assertion failed: Need a reference returning function.
    static_assert(std::is_reference<decltype(array2.get(0))>::value, "Need a reference returning function.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to do anything (other than use a conforming compiler<sup>(1)</sup>). C++ does not allow you to bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary. So with this code:

```
CreditCard& c= array.get(0);
c.pinNumber = 1403; //modification
```

if `array.get(0)` happens to return by value, you will get a compilation error right on the spot.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Visual Studio's compiler has an extension, enabled in the default settings, which allows it to bind references to temporaries (actually rvalues). You can disable this extension with `/Za`